# JQuery DataTables serverside processing with additional variables

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor, datatable, server-side

I've been trying to implement a solution using JQuery datatables with serverside processing to display logs. This has largely been successfull. The datatable declaration is as follows:

```
$('#IndexTable').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "oLanguage": {
    "sSearch": "<div class='editor-label-wide float-left'>" +
        "Search : " +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='editor-field float-left'>" +
                "_INPUT_" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='clear-left'>" +
                "<br/>" +
            "</div>",
        "sLengthMenu": "<div class='editor-label-wide float-left'>" +
                      "Display : " +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='editor-field float-left'>" +
                "_MENU_" +
            "</div>" +
            "<div class='clear-left'>" +
                "<br/>" +
            "</div>",
        "sInfo": "<br/>Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records",
},
"bDestroy": true,
"sAjaxSource": '@Url.Action("List")',
"fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        url: sSource,
        data: aoData,
        success: fnCallback,
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('Error getting logs:' + errorThrown) }
    })
},
"bPaginate": true,
"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
"iDisplayLength": 25,
"aLengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100], [10, 25, 50, 100]],
"aoColumnDefs": [
    { "sName": "Level", "aTargets": [0], "mDataProp": "LogLevel" },
    { "sName": "Source", "aTargets": [1], "mDataProp": "LogSource" },
    { "sName": "Date", "aTargets": [2], "mDataProp": "LogDate" },
    { "sName": "Text", "aTargets": [3], "mDataProp": "LogText" }
    ]
});
```

Then, the contrller action:

```
public JsonResult List(jQueryDataTableParamModel param)
{ ... }
```

Where `jQueryDataTableParamModel` is structured as demonstrated [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part).

This works perfectly for displaying, paging, searching and sorting. Problem is, I have 2 drop-downs that I used when I still did the processing client-side that that filters everything based on 2 of the columns (level and source):

[image]

For this, I need the selected values in the `List` action method. I attempted to do this by simply adding the parameters in the method and passing them through.

```
data: {
    param: aoData,
    levelId: $("#LevelList").val(),
    sourceId: $("#SourceList").val()
},
```

Doing this works, but all the fields in the `jQueryDataTableParamModel` are `null`:

[image]
[image]

I can only assume the problem lies with the differences between:

```
data: aoData
```

and

```
data: {
    param: aoData
},
```

in the ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since figured this out by doing the following:

```
"ajax": {
    "url": "@Url.Action("List")",
    "type": "POST",
    'contentType': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'data': function (data) {
        var tempData = {};
        tempData.pageRequest = data;

        // To addd custom parameters:
        // tempData.customParameter1 = $("#CustomParam").val()

        tempData.levelId = $("#LevelId").val();
        tempData.sourceId = $("#SourceId").val();

        return JSON.stringify(tempData);
    }
},
```

Then these are recieved in the controller action:

```
public JsonResult List(DataTablesPageRequest pageRequest, int levelId, int sourceId)
{ ... }
```

**Note**: I had to update my version of DataTables from 1.9.2 to 1.10.5